# Replace Image with out user noticing

Tags: image, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, file-io

I'm using JSF 2.1.7 + Prime Faces + Prime Faces Mobile.

I have a page that references a image:

```
<img src="/charts/chart1.png"/>
```

There's a separate background process that runs to update chart1.png every 2 minutes. (It gets the image from a particular online url). Here is the code I use to save the image:

```
    public static String saveImage(final String strurl, final String imageFileName){
    //assume the url for the image is valid
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strurl);
        HttpURLConnection  conn = (HttpURLConnection )url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(1000);   //1 sec timeout
        conn.connect();

        File file = new File(imageFileName);
        BufferedImage  image = ImageIO.read(conn.getInputStream());
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

ImageIO.write will delete the existing image file and write out a new one. I believe the above will result in a few milliseconds where the image file is not available, and hence the web user will not be able to see the image.

My questions are:

1) Is it true that there will be a time where the image is temporarily unavailable?

2) And if that is the case, what is a possible solution to fix this, so that user will always have a available image?

Thanks in advance. =)

Answer (score 0):

Heres what i would do

1) First instead of replacing the image, i create a new image chart2.png

2)Then I would change the url in the IMG tag to point to a Servlet,

say [image]
and in that servlet which will be mapped to `/charts/showchart`
, 
And in the servlet i would check for latest available PNG , and stream it as response.

This way you customize how or what image you show.